# Wix setup uses default Application path on Update and not from registry as expected

Tags: wix, windows-installer

We are using Wix Toolset V3.11 to build our setup.

Because of the following declaration, our default installation Path is `C:/Program Files(x86)/Acme/AppName`.

```
<Property Id="ApplicationFolderName" Value="$(var.Manufacturer)\$(var.AppFolderName)"  />
<Property Id="WixAppFolder" Value="WixPerMachineFolder" />
```

Via the 'Advanced' button in the setup we change this path to `C:/Program Files(x86)/Acme/FooBar`:

[image]

The following declaration saves the changed path in the registry:

```
<RegistryKey
    Key="Software\$(var.Manufacturer)\$(var.AppName)"
    Root="HKLM">
    <RegistryValue Id="InstallationRegistry"
        Type="string"
        Name="InstallDir"
        Value="[APPLICATIONFOLDER]" />
    </RegistryKey>
```

Via Regedit.exe I can see the Path `C:/Program Files(x86)/Acme/FooBar` in the Registry as expected. All okay.

**Problem:** But now, when I run a new setup which is an update, then all Files have been moved from the custom folder `C:/Program Files(x86)/Acme/FooBar` to the default folder `C:/Program Files(x86)/Acme/AppName`.

When I execute an update and click on the 'Advanced' button, then the default path `C:/Program Files(x86)/Acme/AppName` is preallocated:

[image]

I use the following markup to query the Path out of the Registry:

```
<Property Id="APPLICATIONFOLDER">
    <RegistrySearch Id='InstallationRegistrySearch' Type='raw' Root='HKLM' Key='Software\$(var.Manufacturer)\$(var.AppName)' Name='InstallDir' />
</Property>
```

Here is the relevant markup:

```
<Fragment>
    <ComponentGroup Id="RootComponents" Directory="APPLICATIONFOLDER">
      <Component Id="RootComponent" Guid="xxxxxxxxx" Win64='yes'>   
        <RegistryKey
          Key="Software\$(var.Manufacturer)\$(var.AppName)"
          Root="HKLM">
          <RegistryValue Id="InstallationRegistry"
                         Type="string"
                         Name="InstallDir"
                         Value="[APPLICATIONFOLDER]" />
        </RegistryKey>

      </Component>      
    </ComponentGroup>

    [...]


<Product ...>
    <Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">
      <Directory Id="PROGRAMFILESPATH" Name="$(var.ProgramFilesPath)">
        <Directory Id="ManufacturerFolder" Name="$(var.Manufacturer)">
          <Directory Id="APPLICATIONFOLDER" Name="$(var.AppFolderName)" >

            <!-- here are the application files (e.g. Appname.exe)-->
            [...]

          </Directory>
        </Directory>
      </Directory>      
    </Directory>


    [...]

    <Property Id="ApplicationFolderName" Value="$(var.Manufacturer)\$(var.AppFolderName)"  />
    <Property Id="WixAppFolder" Value="WixPerMachineFolder" />

    <Property Id="APPLICATIONFOLDER">
      <RegistrySearch Id='InstallationRegistrySearch' Type='raw' Root='HKLM' Key='Software\$(var.Manufacturer)\$(var.AppName)' Name='InstallDir' />
    </Property>

    <Property Id="PREVIOUSVERSIONSINSTALLED" Secure="yes" />
    <Property Id="ALLUSERS" Value="1"/>

    [...]

    <UI>
      [...]
      <UIRef Id="WixUI_Advanced"/>
    </UI>
</Product>
```

What are we doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***Remember Properties***: Property values are not auto-magically persisted by MSI, hence the need for patterns such as the "[**Remember Property Pattern**](http://robmensching.com/blog/posts/2010/5/2/the-wix-toolsets-remember-property-pattern/)".

***Bitness***: It looks like you are reading back from the registry, but could it be that you have a "**bitness problem**"? In other words you read from the **x64-section** of the registry and not the **x86-section**? (or vice versa).

- **`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Manufacturer\Acme\Program`**
- **`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Manufacturer\Acme\Program`**